# Creating calendar event with attendees

Tags: google-calendar-api

I tried to create a google calendar event with attendees, and it didn't work (threw an error of domain wide delegation).

I activated the domain wide delegation and rerun the script, ending with the same error,

Which lead me to wonder, does the Domain Wide Delegation require a G-Suite account?

- I'm using a service account
- Without the Attendees the scripts works fine
- The service account has a calendar shared to it, and the service account has modify permissions to this calendar (events without attendees are created successfully)
- I want to create the events on this calendar and add attendees to the event (If i will be able to create events to a calendar that's not shared with the service account it would be preferred)

Answer (score 0):

> does the Domain Wide Delegation require a G-Suite account?

**Domain-wide delegation means that you use a service-account that acts on behalf on users in your (GSuite!) domain. If you do not have a GSuite account, you cannot have a GSuite domain and consequently no users in this domain. See [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).**

> Without the Attendees the scripts works fine

**This issue has been [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761425) on Google's public issue tracker. Basically, right now there there restrictions for creation of events with attendees with a service account, especially when the attendees are outside of your domain. The current workaround would be not to use a service account for creation of events with attendees.**

I hope this information is useful for you!

Comment: Would this work with the default app engine service account that runs in cloud functions? I am not sure if that one is tied to the domain in any way